# Windows MFT (Media Foundation Transform) decoder not returning proper sample time or duration

Tags: c++, windows, h.264, ms-media-foundation

To decode a H264 stream with the Windows Media foundation Transform, the work flow is currently something like this:

```
IMFSample sample;
sample->SetTime(time_in_ns);
sample->SetDuration(duration_in_ns);
sample->AddBuffer(buffer);

// Feed IMFSample to decoder
mDecoder->ProcessInput(0, sample, 0);

// Get output from decoder.
/* create outputsample that will receive content */ { ... }
MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER output = {0};
output.pSample = outputsample;
DWORD status = 0;
HRESULT hr = mDecoder->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &output, &status);
DWORD status = 0;
hr = mDecoder->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &output, &status);
if (output.pEvents) {
  // We must release this, as per the IMFTransform::ProcessOutput()
  // MSDN documentation.
  output.pEvents->Release();
  output.pEvents = nullptr;
}

if (hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_STREAM_CHANGE) {
  // Type change, probably geometric aperture change.
  // Reconfigure decoder output type, so that GetOutputMediaType()
} else if (hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT) {
  // Not enough input to produce output.
} else if (!output.pSample) {
  return S_OK;
} else }
  // Process output
}
```

}

When we have fed all data to the MFT decoder, we must drain it:

```
mDecoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_DRAIN, 0);
```

Now, one thing with the WMF H264 decoder, is that it will typically not output anything before having been called with over 30 compressed h264 frames regardless of the size of the h264 sliding window. Latency is very high...

I'm encountering an issue that is very troublesome.
With a video made only of keyframes, and which has only 15 frames, each being 2s long, the first frame having a presentation time of non-zero (this stream is from live content, so first frame is typically in epos time)
So without draining the decoder, nothing will come out of the decoder as it hasn't received enough frames.

However, once the decoder is drained, the decoded frame will come out. HOWEVER, the MFT decoder has set all durations to 33.6ms only and the presentation time of the first sample coming out is always 0.
The original duration and presentation time have been lost.

If you provide over 30 frames to the h264 decoder, then both duration and pts are valid...

I haven't yet found a way to get the WMF decoder to output samples with the proper value.
It appears that if you have to drain the decoder before it has output any samples by itself, then it's totally broken...

Has anyone experienced such problems? How did you get around it?

Thank you in advance

Edit: a sample of the video is available on http://people.mozilla.org/~jyavenard/mediatest/fragmented/1301869.mp4
Playing this video with Firefox will causes it to play extremely quickly due to the problems described above.

Comment: You should try `CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode` [[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd797815), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh447590)].

Comment: low latency is only available from Window 8 and later. Also, incompatible with anything containing B-Frames. And additionally, got plenty of driver crashes when enabled... Low Latency would help here, though would still have the same problem if I had < 8 frames.

Comment: I am afraid all you mentioned is behavior by design. Output frames are available asynchronously (esp. when in DXVA mode), low latency in Windows 8+ to slightly improve things, changed timings when H.264 embeds time related data. Driver crashes need driver updates, of course. Software-only decoder might have more predictable behavior, I suppose.

Comment: So that MFT returns the wrong timestamp and the wrong duration is by design? I find that hard to believe :)

Comment: Not necessarily wrong if you think of timing information in the H.264 bitstream. It might be just preferred to your timestamps.

Comment: Problem is that in our application, I must get back to original timestamps or at least proper duration in between. The original timestamps are 2s appart. What comes out start at 0 with 33.6ms appart. I can't easily reconstruct the original timing information with what comes out of the decoder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that your work flow is correct. I think you should do something like this:

```
do
{
    ...
    hr = mDecoder->ProcessInput(0, sample, 0);
    if(FAILED(hr))
      break;
    ...
    hr = mDecoder->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &output, &status);
    if(FAILED(hr) && hr != MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT)
      break;
}
while(hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // You have a valid decoded frame here
}
```

The idea is to keep calling ProcessInput/ProcessOuptut while ProcessOutput returns MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT. MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT means that decoder needs more input. I think that with this loop you won't need to drain the decoder.

Comment: What you describe is no different to what I have. I presented on the workflow for ONE frame only. Of course if you have more than one frame you will loop.... The issue however is that if you call ProcessInput less than 30 times, you typically have nothing coming out of ProcessOutput. This is where draining is required.

Comment: "MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT means that decoder needs more input" sure... but what if you have nothing more to give to the decoder as you've reached the end of the stream?

Comment: How do you set the input type of the decoder? Do you set a fully described IMFMediaType or only major type and subtype? Have you checked if ProcessOutput returns MF_E_TRANSFORM_STREAM_CHANGE? Can you try to call ProcessInput in a loop to see if it will return MF_E_NOTACCEPTING? I now see that you don't have enough frames to feed to decoder, but it might need a full GOP to be provided before outputting a sample. Do you have the start codes included in each frame? The decoder skips bytes until it finds a valid sequence parameter set (SPS) and picture parameter set (PPS) in the byte stream.

Comment: If nothing else works can you try to generate black frames to feed to decoder before your actual data to see if it will change the behavior?

Comment: You can also try to set discontinuity (MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity) to TRUE on the first sample that you feed to the decoder. 
Btw, you said you fed only keyframes to the decoder. Do you mean you only receive "I frames" from your live content source?

Comment: Also how do you set MF_MT_FRAME_RATE for the input type, because 2 seconds is a high value for the frame duration.
What about the MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE ?

Comment: Yes, ProcessOutput does return MF_E_TRANSFORM_STREAM_CHANGE  prior returning the first sample. Further some mention about h264 timing in there, I started to look deeper in the SPS, and indeed this troublesome video set timing_info_present_flag to true with fixed_frame_rate_flag = true as well. I then found this MS document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553440(v=vs.85).aspx which mentions of using 29.976fps by default if nothing is found in the SPS. The SPS does have num_units_in_tick = 1 and time_scale = 50

Comment: Yes, the first frame contains both SPS and PPS in the bytestream. This is automatically added as the MFT expect AnnexB content. Copying the SPS and PPS to the bytestream is done as part of the AVCC -> AnnexB conversion... I have played with MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity as well, it made no difference

Comment: Does the MF_MT_FRAME_RATE change after the MF_E_TRANSFORM_STREAM_CHANGE ?

Comment: Do you use the CLSID_CMSH264RemuxMFT instead of CLSID_CMSH264DecoderMFT? Because the link you provided refers to the remux MFT.

Comment: http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-153019.html
num_units_in_tick = 1 and time_scale = 50
correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't this give 25 FPS?

Comment: yes.. I believe it looks like it should be 25fps. MFT returns as if it was 29.976Hz though (ntsc). We do use CLSID_CMSH264DecoderMFT.. I only pointed to that link because the outcome is exactly following what is described in that article. Both pts and duration are being rewritten. Very weird that enabling low latency mode would cause a different behaviour

Comment: Indeed it seems that with low latency disabled it needs to buffer more samples. But I'm still not convinced that it won't work with proper FPS values set in num_units_in_tick and time_scale. Can you change those values? The MF_MT_FRAME_RATE is also important for the input media type. Can you try to set a fully described media type as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797815(v=vs.85).aspx following after "Input Types"

Comment: "To avoid an initial format change, provide as much information in the input type as possible"

Comment: i do not know the initial frame rate, this is not an information provided by the MP4 metadata. Only the cts/dts/duration are provided... We are expecting to get an initial format change, in fact our code rely on it to properly set the dxva output...

Comment: "With a video made only of keyframes, and which has only 15 frames, each being 2s long" - it seems that you expect the fps to be 1/2 frame per second?
I still think you need to specify the fully described input and output (dxva ) type.

Comment: That extract is made of 15 frames.. but the entire stream isn't. This is coming from a live stream. Some frames were dropped, when that happens , the streaming code drop the frames and extend the duration of the previous key frame..